# Sweetalert not working in javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css

im not getting any errors when running the file

this is in my javascript file

```
// Load script
 var filerefjs = document.createElement('script');
 filerefjs.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
 filerefjs.setAttribute("src", "../../rotateScreen/dist/sweetalert.min.js");

 // Load CSS file
 var filerefcss = document.createElement("link");
 filerefcss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
 filerefcss.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
 filerefcss.setAttribute("href", "../../rotateScreen/dist/sweetalert.css");
```

and then trying to call sweetAlert instead of standard alert
using a function, nothing happens when clicking the button in my index file

```
 
function dynamicSubmit(decisionTree) {

    if (dt.type == "terminal") {
        console.log("terminal is true")
        //sweetAlert("The Trial this patient is eligible for is " + dt.text);
        sweetAlert("Good job!", +dt.text, "success");
        return;
    }
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("member");
    var i = 0, len = radios.length;
    var checked = false;
    var userAnswer;

    //basically see what choice the user made
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            checked = true;
            userAnswer = radios[i].value;
        }
    }

    // if user click submit button without selecting any option, alert box should be say "please select choice answer".
    if (!checked) {
       // alert("please select choice answer");
       sweetAlert("Error", "select a choice", "warning");
        //return;
    }
```

Comment: Is `+` redundant in `+dt.text`?

Comment: doesnt  make a difference, nothing happens still

Comment: how the event created? please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before you ask, unless your questions is not Reproducible

Comment: see edit for above